# Processing area of interests within Grass GIS

Tags: grass-gis

I'm looking to process a region within a satellite image in Grass GIS. In ENVI I would create a region of interest (.roi) and then create a subset.

If I have coordinates for a rectangle within my image, can I create a min/max bounding box and mask the area inside, then invert the mask so processing only applies to areas inside the region of interest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For that, you have the commands [g.region](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/g.region.html) and [r.mask](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.mask.html) (no needs to create new layers):

1. `g.region` (in Settings/Region or in the GRASS shell)

> The region's cell resolution defines the size of the smallest piece of data recognized (imported, analyzed, displayed, stored, etc.) by GRASS modules affected by the current region settings. The north-south and east-west cell resolutions need not be the same, thus allowing non-square data cells to exist.

2. `r.mask` (in Raster/MASK (`r.mask`) or in the GRASS shell)

> The MASK will block out certain areas of a raster map from analysis and/or display, by "hiding" them from sight of other GRASS modules

The command is (only with raster layers)

```
GRASS 6.4.3 (geol):~ > r.mask input raster_layer
```

**So, if you want to work only on a region of interest** (all figures come from [GRASS GIS for beginners: 6 - masks (MASK) and their uses](http://www.portailsig.org/content/grass-gis-pas-pas-pour-les-debutants-6-les-masques-mask-et-leurs-utilisations-rapport-avec-l), in French)

[image]

### Example: I want to work on a specific zone of a raster layer (DEM here) to create contour lines.

1)  To create a MASK, **I use a vector layer that I converted to raster** using  the command [v.to.rast](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.to.rast.html)  (from the menu File/Map type conversion/Vector To Raster (`v.to.rast`))

[image]

2) The MASK layer is created from this resulting layer (`r.mask input resulting_layer`) and the result is:

[image]

3) Now, I apply [r.contour](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.contour.html) to this zone:

[image]

4) If I remove the existing MASK, it can be seen that the processing is limited to the MASK zone (the region of interest)

[image]

### Other example, I want to extract the values of a DEM between X meters and Y meters:

[image]

1) I create the MASK layer with [r.mapcalc](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.mapcalc.html) or [r.mapcalculator](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.mapcalculator.html)

[image]

[image]

2) and the result is:

[image]

The MASK  works also in 3D with nviz:

[image]

And, if you want, you can create a new layer with the result, but these are only 2 examples, the possibilities are endless!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about doing this on one layer but I have extracted the area of interest before and then just working on that. When I did it I used the patch function but I think [clipper](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/11/tip-clip-raster-in-irregular-shape.html) will also work. After you're done you could just see about melding the two layers together again.